what is the alternative way to achieve rmi remoting call in spring framework 6.x n above
We have a springboot project on 2,x version which we are migrating to 3.x version and java 21, we found that RmiProxyFactoryBean is not supported in spring framework 6.x n above
we are creating a bean using RmiProxyFactoryBean and calling our rmi service hosted on other server. Now issue is in spring framework 6.x n above RmiProxyFactoryBean is completely removed , so how to achieve the service call instead of RmiProxyFactoryBean ?

below is the invocation?
